# Selecting All Features within Feature Dataset in ArcSDE Database using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, select-by-location

I'm trying to create a script tool to select all the features within a user-specified area of interest then run the Data Reviewer extension. I've encountered an issue trying to select features from a feature dataset. There are multiple feature datasets in my sde database, and I want to select all feature classes from one specific feature dataset. The code below runs up to the `selected_aoi` variable.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = "true"

# User path to reviewer workspace
rev_workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# RBJ file path
rbj_file = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Open session
session_num = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Select user AOI's using SQL
user_AOI = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

# Path to production workspace
prod_workspace = r"X:\DataConnections\Utilities.sde"

# Path to the Water Distribution Feature Dataset
wat_fc_dataset = os.path.join(prod_workspace, "/Utilities.WaterDistribution")

# Select the AOI and Run Data Reviewer
try:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Starting Process")
    aoi_fc_select = os.path.join(prod_workspace + 
                         "/Utilities.ModelCorrections/Utilities.WaterOperationalAreaCorrections")

    arcpy.AddMessage("Selecting AOI")
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(aoi_fc_select, "selected_aoi_lyr", user_AOI)
    arcpy.AddMessage("AOI Selected")
    
    arcpy.AddMessage("Selecting features in AOI")
    selected_aoi = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("selected_aoi_layer", "intersect", wat_fc_dataset)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Features in AOI selected")

    # Run the RBJ file
    arcpy.AddMessage("Running Data Reviewer on selected features")
    arcpy.ExecuteReviewerBatchJob_Reviewer(rev_workspace,session_num,rbj_file,prod_workspace, selected_aoi)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Process Completed")

except:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Failed to Execute")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the code when trying to select the layer.

**Make Feature Layer code:**

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(aoi_fc_select, "selected_aoi_lyr", user_AOI)
```

**Selection code:**

```
selected_aoi = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("selected_aoi_layer", "intersect", wat_fc_dataset)
```

The code made a layer called "selected_aoi_lyr" but it is trying to select from a non-existent "selected_aoi_layer" ("lyr" vs "layer").

This is a common accident to make when using MakeFeatureLayer. A great way of avoiding this is to assign new feature layers to variables instead; like so:

```
    arcpy.AddMessage("Selecting AOI")
    feature_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(aoi_fc_select, "selected_aoi_lyr", user_AOI)
    arcpy.AddMessage("AOI Selected")
    
    arcpy.AddMessage("Selecting features in AOI")
    selected_aoi = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(feature_layer , "intersect", wat_fc_dataset)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Features in AOI selected")
```

That way instead of having to write the string name for the feature layer, it uses a variable instead. Most IDE's would then say if a typo was made as the variable wouldn't exist, but won't tell you if it is in a string.

i.e

IDE's will say this syntax looks ok

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(aoi_fc_select, "feature_layer", user_AOI)
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("feature_lyr", "intersect", wat_fc_dataset)
```

IDE's will say that feature_lyr doesn't exist

```
feature_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(aoi_fc_select, "feature_layer", user_AOI)
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(feature_lyr, "intersect", wat_fc_dataset)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I overlooked that. How could I go about selecting all features in multiple feature classes by location?